# Calculo matemáticos

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

espero poder tener el placer de alguien que pueda ayudar con el siguiente problema.
he intentado hacer una división en una fracción ósea al introducir y esto me da error al introducir el cero sin terminar de escribir la fracción.

textbox -- **TbxM2** -- introduzco **1**

texLargo -- **TbxLargo** -- introduzco **0.39**

textAltura -- **TbxAltura** -- introduzco **0.19**

seria algo asi **tbxTotal** = **1 / (0.39 * 0.19)**

```
 decimal Largo = 0, Altura = 0, M2 = 0;

  public void Resultados(decimal largo, decimal aLtura, decimal m2)
    {
            decimal multipl = m2 / (largo * aLtura);
            tbxTotal.Text = multipl.ToString();
    }
```

// Textbox Largo

```
 private void tbxLargo_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            Largo = Convert.ToDecimal(tbxLargo.Text.ToString());
            Resultados(Largo, Altura,M2);
    }
```

// Textbox Altura

```
 private void tbxAltura_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Altura= Convert.ToDecimal(tbxAltura.Text.ToString());
        Resultados(Largo, Altura,M2);
}
```

// Textbox M2

```
 private void tbxM2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        M2= Convert.ToDecimal(tbxM2.Text.ToString());
        Resultados(Largo, Altura,M2);
}
```

Comment: ¿Seguro que esto es una declaración correcta `0.39m;`?, lo pregunto por que no lo veo  como un tipo de dato válido

Comment: ese dato lo puse como ejemplo, pero igual, el caso es que cuando quiero ingresar 0.3, o 0.9 al solo darle al cero me da error

Comment: No entiendo lo que intentas decir, al final que es lo que quieres hacer, dividir dos números decimales? No entiendo lo que quieres decir con que al ingresar el cero automáticamente te da error

Comment: déjame editar mi consulta, creo que luego que lo haga podría ser mas claro

Comment: @AlynsonTorres, podrías decirme si la respuesta dada te fue útil, gracias

Comment: Perdón creí haber dado mi repuesta, si fue útil, a pesar que encontré varias soluciones mas cómoda para realizar las operaciones matemáticas.

Comment: @AlynsonTorres, si te fue util te agradeceria el voto, y que compartieras esas soluciones de las que hablas ya que puede serle util a otros, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error debe estar en que debes estar dividiendo algún número entre **0**, y **la división entre** **0** **no está definida**, prueba esto:

```
public void Resultados(decimal largo, decimal altura, decimal m2)
{
   if(largo != 0 && altura != 0)
   {
      decimal multipl = m2 / (largo * aLtura);
      tbxTotal.Text = multipl.ToString();
   }
}
```

Se comprueba que **largo** y **altura** no sean **0**, de no ser **0** pues se procede a ejecutar el cálculo.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando introduces el 0 y se ejecuta la función Resultados, el divisor es 0 y por tanto se produce un error. Antes de hacer la división deberías comprobar que el divisor no es 0.